# WithRouter Replace Component does not work React-Router-V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm upgrading react router to react router v6. In the newest version `withRouter` is not supported anymore. I implemented this wrapper as a replacement.

```
export const withRouter = Component => {
  const Wrapper = props => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return <Component navigate={navigate} {...props} />;
  };

  return Wrapper;
};
```

I implemented it like that

```
export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Layout)
);
```

basically the wrapper is at the same spot as the original withRouter was in the application.

Currently I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: [Wrapper] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

I exchanged `<Component navigate={navigate} {...props}/>` with `<Route navigate={navigate} {...props}/>`, however I still get the same error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wrapper` is the returned component that you appear to be trying to render as a route component in a `Routes` component, but as the error points out, this is an invariant violation.

Given:

```
export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Layout)
);
```

It seems you are trying to directly render this component in the `Routes` component, something like:

```
<Routes>
  <DecoratedLayout> // <-- Not a Route component!!
    <Route ....... />
    ...

  </DecoratedLayout>
</Routes>
```

This is invalid though. In this example the `DecoratedLayout` component should be rendered as a Wrapper component (*renders `children` prop*) or on a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) (*renders `Outlet` component*).

As a Wrapper component:

```
<Routes>
  <Route 
    path="...."
    element={(
      <DecoratedLayout>
        ...
      </DecoratedLayout>
    )}
  />
  ...
</Routes>
```

As a Layout Route:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<DecoratedLayout />}>
    <Route ....... />
    ...
  </Route>
  ...
</Routes>
```